# where's a good reference and community for help with getting started on Bayesian time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, bayesian

I am trying to learn the basics of Bayesian time series analysis, but am having trouble finding some up-to-date basic examples and a discussion forum where I might be able to get some guidance.  (There are a number of questions here ostensibly similar, but they are quite old and I get the impression that the field has moved on a lot since they were answered.)

The problem I would like to be able to solve regards the maximum waiting time at US airports as reported by the CBT at https://awt.cbp.gov/

I have downloaded all the available data and am able to easily extract and plot the time series for a particular airport terminal on a particular weekday/time, (for example for JFK Terminal 8,for all flights arriving 1500-1600 on Wednesdays in April:

[image]

It is easy to run some basic stats on this to get an expected value and distribution of wait times for the next year, but I can't help but feel that my distribution would be better informed if I were to take into account, somehow, any trend in the data, data from other weekdays, and data from neighboring hour periods.

Are there any suggestions for where I might go for a gentle discussion of what and how I could do?

Comment: Rather than time series, I think your problem calls for a [queuing model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/545353) (e.g., [Simaiakis & Balakrishnan](https://doi.org/10.1287/trsc.2015.0603)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.